# How to check the type of user logged in django?

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-queryset

I want to check the type of user logged in and return the template according to the user logged in. How can I check the type of user?
This is my django model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User , on_delete= models.CASCADE)

class Student(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    rollNo = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.rollNo)

class Supervisor(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    teacher_ID = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.profile)
```

I have tried the following statements but it gives an error:

```
def homePage(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request , 'accounts/login.html')
    
    user = request.user

    is_student = Student.objects.filter(profile__user=user).exists()

    is_supervisor = Supervisor.objects.filter(profile__user=user).exists()
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

Error:
**Unsupported lookup 'user' for OneToOneField or join on the field not permitted.**

Answer (score 0):

`student.profile` is a `User` instance. as such it does not have a `user` field. That what the error is trying to communicate.
The following should work:

```
def homePage(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request , 'accounts/login.html')
    
    user = request.user

    is_student = Student.objects.filter(profile=user).exists()

    is_supervisor = Supervisor.objects.filter(profile=user).exists()
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```